# Get index by specific search term with a list in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list as follows:

```
Cat, Green, 10
Cat, Green, 1
Dog, Red, 4
Cat, Blue, 2
```

Each item is just a comma seperated string element in a list.

I would like to get all the index values of all the elements in the above list that contain cat and 10 or contain cat and 2. So basically i should get the index values 0 and 3 returned from the query on the list. Can anyone show me how i can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var query = list.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                .Where(pair => pair.item.Name == "Cat" && 
                               (pair.item.Value == 10 || pair.item.Value == 2))
                .Select(pair => pair.index);
```

(That's assuming the elements have properties of Name and Value for the first and third columns you've shown.)

EDIT: Okay, if you're just working with strings, you could use:

```
var query = list.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                .Where(pair => pair.item.StartsWith("Cat,") &&
                               (pair.item.EndsWith(", 10") || 
                                pair.item.EndsWith(", 2"))
                .Select(pair => pair.index);
```

Alternatively, parse the list into something a little more pleasant to start with...

Comment: there is no properties named name or value. The Cat, Green, 10 entries are just comma seperated string stored in a string list\

Comment: @KerryL: It would have been nice if you'd made that clear to start with.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to loop through the list and use `string.Contains`, `string.StartsWith` & `string.EndsWith`, or a Regex to test if the current item is what you are looking for.  Not particularly efficient but fairly easy to write.